# N-polynomial addition not working

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm not sure if I'd sound dumb, but still..I want to develop a program using linked list where I could add upto 5 Polynomials. The code I could come up with is..

```
struct node
{
    int exp,coeff;
    struct node *next;
} *start[5]={NULL};

void read()
{
    struct node *current,*newnode;
    int n,i,max,j;
    printf("How many poly?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nDetails of poly %d\n",i);
        printf("Max degree:");
        scanf("%d",&max);
        for(j=max;j>=0;j--)
        {
            newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(newnode));
            printf("\nEnter coeff of %d:",j);
            scanf("%d",&newnode->coeff);
            newnode->exp=j;
            if(start[i]==NULL)
            {
                printf("a%d",start[i]);
                start[i]=newnode;
                newnode->next=NULL;
                printf("%d,%d",start[i],start[i]->next);
            }
            else if(start[i]->next==NULL)
            {
                printf("b");
                start[i]->next=newnode;
                newnode->next=NULL;
                printf("%d",start[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("c");
                current=start[i];
                while(current->next!=NULL)
                    current=current->next;
                current->next=newnode;
                newnode->next=NULL;
                printf("%d",start[i]);
            }   
        }
    }   
}

void sum()
{
    struct node *curr1,*curr2,*tmp;
    int i,co,ex;
    curr1=start[0];
    while(curr1!=NULL)
    {   
        for(i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            co=0;
            if(curr1==start[i])
                tmp=start[i];
            else
                tmp=tmp->next;
            curr2=tmp;
            if(curr1->exp==curr2->exp)
            {
                if(co==0)
                    co=co+curr1->coeff+curr2->coeff;
                else
                    co=co+curr2->coeff;
                ex=curr1->exp;
                break;
            }
            else if(curr1->exp>curr2->exp)
            {   
                ex=curr1->exp;
                if(co==0)
                    co=co+curr1->coeff;
                else
                    break;
            }
            else
            {   
                ex=curr2->exp;
                if(co==0)
                    co=co+curr2->coeff;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("%dX^%d",co,ex);
        curr1=curr1->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    read();
    printf("result:\n");
    sum();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But on executing,only the first polynomial is getting read.ie, 'i' loop work only once. I tried to check my read function and notice the second condition was not working.ie,this one:

```
else if(start[i]->next==NULL)    
{
    printf("b");
    start[i]->next=newnode;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    printf("%d",start[i]);
}
```

That print b was to check if program entered this block LOL.
Somebody help me with this please...

Comment: Debugger..................

Comment: Unrelated: At SO spaces come pretty cheap, use them

Comment: @4386427 Spacesareincriiticalshortage.Usetabswheneverpossible. Togetherwecanmakeitthroughthisdifficulttime.;-)

Comment: Thanks guys I'll try it out and update

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(newnode));  // This will allocate space for 
                                                 // a pointer to struct node
```

should be

```
newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));  // This will allocate space for 
                                                     // a struct node
```

or better as suggested by @chux

```
newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);         // This will allocate space for 
                                           // whatever newnode points to. In
                                           // this case a struct node
```

Not sure it makes a difference but I would change:

```
start[5]={NULL};
```

into

```
start[5]={NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

Comment: Recommend `newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);`